# How to match time range if to_date can be Null in Django?

Tags: django, date, filter

I have two date, let's say from_date and to_date, and I have column with prices for that range. It looks like this in my models:

```
class PriceList(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Start date")
    to_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="End_date", null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Models, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="EUR/h", max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)
```

I know how to get record for the correct product in a period **if** a to_date is available, but I am not sure how to fetch it if it is Null, that means from from_date to forever (until changed). And, obviously, would like to have query that will work in both scenarios - if ther is a to_date and if it Null.

Comment: {% if obj.to_date is None %}inside logic{% endif%}

Comment: That would be in template. I was asking how to construct query to match correct record in my database in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that tried to help. In the end I ended up using what I hoped I could avoid, having multiple Q objects in my query. I hoped for more elegant way, maybe there is still hope for it :)

```
current_price = Pricelist.objects.get(Q(id=tmp_id) & (Q(from_date__lte=datetime.today()) & Q(to_date__gte=datetime.today()) | Q(from_date__lte=datetime.today()) & Q(to_date=None))).price
```

Hope this might help someone else looking for same issue.
And if anyone has something smarter and more elegant, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a class method for getting the price, something like this :

```
def get_total_price(self):
    try:
        diff = self.to_date - self.from_date
        days = diff.days
        hours = days * 24 +  (diff.seconds / 3600) 
        total_price = hours * float(self.price)
    except Exception as e:
    # log.info(e)
        total_price = 0
    return total_price
```

Note that this is not gonna save total_price to the db as it’s just a calculated field, but you have access to the total price from each instance of the class

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your code, but it is not what I was looking for. It was just about matching query with situation when I have a price for period date_A to date_B, and date_A to Null -  in this case meaning "forever". In the end I wrote something that you can see in my answer, but I hoped that it could be done more elegantly.